# Metadata zip created via force:mdapi:convert fails during deploy due to 3rd party namespaces

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, mdapi

We have a working DX project and are trying to deploy our code to full copy via sfdx force:mdapi:deploy command. Creating a zip file works fine, sadly the deployment fails with error message:

```
force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\CloudingoAgent__STZ__c.field-meta.xml                        
Cannot create a new component with the namespace: CloudingoAgent.  Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API
```

1. It seems that mdapi:convert command does try to assemble the whole Account object based on our change in a RecordType specific Picklist with all the 3rd party managed fields. Is there a way to avoid 3rd party interferance with our deploys?
2. Do we really need to remove 3rd party applications for every deploy and reinstall those after every deploy?
3. We tried to follow deployment procedures provided by [Salesforce trailhead recommendations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/org-development-model/test-and-deploy-changes?trail_id=determine-which-application-lifecycle-management-model-is-right-for-you). Is there a better process to follow?

Any suggestions and experience sharing is welcome.
Thank you.